# Error "function 'mb_output_handler' not found" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I run following command in php laravel 3.2 project folder

```
php artisan key:generate
```

then I get this warning

> Warning: ob_start(): function 'mb_output_handler' not found or invalid function name in /Users/zafar/Sites/laravel-todo/laravel/core.php on line 32

In my phpinfo.php, I already have mbstring enabled. However, when I do `php --ri mbstring` then it says `Extension 'mbstring' not present.`. How can I solve this problem? I use Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5. I upgraded my php to php 5.4.13 using this http://php-osx.liip.ch/ recently.

**Update**

In my phpinfo file the php version is `PHP Version 5.4.13` but when I do `php -v` it shows following output

```
PHP 5.4.11 (cli) (built: Jan 26 2013 20:10:19) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

**Update 2**

when I run `php -i` then it shows following output

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.11

System => Darwin Zafars-MacBook-Pro.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Jan 26 2013 20:09:37
Configure Command =>  './configure' 
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg
Registered Stream Filters => convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

Core

PHP Version => 5.4.11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
```

And when I did `which php` it gives me this path `/usr/local/bin/php` and then I did `/usr/local/bin/php -i` which gives me following output

```
    phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.11

System => Darwin Zafars-MacBook-Pro.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Jan 26 2013 20:09:37
Configure Command =>  './configure' 
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg
Registered Stream Filters => convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

Core

PHP Version => 5.4.11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
```

**Update 3**

When I run `/usr/local/php5/bin/php -i` I get following output

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php-mbstring.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php-mbstring.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php-mbstring.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php-mbstring.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.13

System => Darwin Zafars-MacBook-Pro.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Mar 19 2013 17:10:14
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/php5' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5/php.d' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-ldap' '--with-xmlrpc' '--enable-exif' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-zip' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--with-iodbc' '--with-mhash' '--enable-fpm' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-dtrace' '--with-iconv=/usr/local/php5' '--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-mssql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-libxml-dir=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-imap=../imap-2007f' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-gettext=/usr/local/php5' '--with-curl=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-tidy=/usr/local/php5' '--with-gmp=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-readline=shared,/usr/local/php5'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/php5/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-apc.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-curl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-gmp.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-intl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-memcache.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mongo.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mssql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-oauth.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pdo_dblib.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-readline.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-solr.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-twig.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-uploadprogress.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xhprof.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-xsl.ini,
/usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini

PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
```

Comment: I read somewhere (can't remember where) that you have to enable php_mysql.dll and php_mysqli.dll as well. Do you have that?

Comment: in phpinfo.php file it is enabled. But with `php --ri mysql` and `php --ri mysqli` says `Extension 'mysql' not present` and `Extension 'mysql' not present`

Comment: Maybe it's not about the mbstring. Error says "or invalid function name". Take a look at the core.php... ?

Comment: Note that PHP on the console may use a different "php.ini" to the one in your web server. Check the first 20 lines of your `php -i` to see where it is looking.

Comment: Also, do `which php` to see what is being run - you seem to have two versions installed. I'd expect one is the stock OS X copy, and the other you installed yourself. Try `/path/to/your/php -i` to see if that gives you different results.

Comment: I am updating my post.

Comment: Ah, running `php` and the output of `which php` you will run the same binary; you need to find the _other_ instance of it. Try `locate php | less` to find other other one. With Macports, my custom installation is in "/opt/local/bin/php".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, from [the documentation](http://php-osx.liip.ch/#faq) you've cited:

> php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but installs everyting in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.

Try running `/usr/local/php5/bin/php -i` at your console, to see what you have installed.

Comment: I tried [this search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=php_osx+liip+Unable+to+load+dynamic+library+mbstring) and [got this](https://github.com/liip/php-osx/issues/38). Any good?

Comment: @x4ph4r: how far did you get with this?