# ob_start() failed to create buffer in laravel three

Tags: php, redis, laravel

I am using Laravel 3 for a project, and I've made a little `cronjob script`, and when I moved to the new server it keeps saying:

> Warning: `ob_start()`: function '`mb_output_handler`' not found or invalid function name 
>   and
>   Notice: `ob_start()`: failed to create buffer

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716277/error-function-mb-output-handler-not-found-in-laravel), which may help sort your issue. Are you using OSX?

Comment: not using OSX. The project is on a ubuntu server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new server is Ubuntu? Are your development server and the "new server" the same OS? Same PHP versions?

It's possible the two servers are *completely* different!

Can you show your cronjob? (Does it attempt to use a specific php binary via a `#!/usr/bin/env php` call ?

### One possibility for Ubuntu:

PHP run in CLI *can* be different from being run in Apache, and especially is likely different if you're using php5-fpm with Nginx.

They each can have their own php.ini and different extensions loaded.

As you said, you're using Ubuntu Server. If you're using php 5.5, you may note a few things in `/etc/php5`:

```
/etc/php5/mods-available  # All mods available / installed
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini     # php.ini for CLI-called php5
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d      # Directory of symlinks to extensions in mods-available!
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini # php.ini for Apache-run php5
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d  # Symlinks to mods-available extensions
```

So, php in CLI vs Apache2 vs PHP-FPM can all have different extensions loaded and separated php.ini's installed.

Perhaps the cli-based one (likely what the cronjob is using) may be a different version of PHP (!) or loading a different .ini file and/or set of extensions.

Comment: they are using a different php.ini, I know that. The php version is 5.4.13 and my guess is that there is a problem with the mbstring in php.ini , I was trying to get that package from somewhere, but couldn't find it