# How to fix ob_start(): failed to create buffer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm facing an issue in laravel

> "ob_start(): failed to create buffer"

. Can anyone help me to resolve this? I'm using Linux VPS. CentOS 6.9

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ob\_start() failed to create buffer in laravel three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787514/ob-start-failed-to-create-buffer-in-laravel-three)

Comment: But it din't resolve the issue